# Rsync filter: "OS X label"

Tags: macos

On OS X, can I rsync selectively based on the file label as set in the Finder?

e.g. rsync all files and directories labelled "green".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with `rsync` alone. `rsync` doesn't know how to read or act on OS X file meta data, which labels happen to be. But, you can pass `rsync` an explicit list of files to sync. Combine this with the fact that you can use [mdls](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/mdls.1.html) to read label information on files from the command line and you could build a list of files and send that list to rsync.

```
> mdls -name kMDItemFSLabel Amanda\ Palmer\ \&\ The\ Grand\ Theft\ Orchestra\ --\ Do\ It\ With\ a\ Rockstar.mp3 
kMDItemFSLabel = 4
```

Comment: I was hoping rsync would take a "predicate function" for its filtering so that it would run it against all candidate files..

Comment: Filters are as good as it gets in rsync and they can't run commands or scripts for you to determine filter applicability. It's pattern based filtering only. See: http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html, section `FILTER RULES`.

Comment: I found my solution: build a file list using mdfind (e.g. mdfind -onlyin Media/E-Books "kMDItemFSLabel == 2") and feed it into rsync. You did not recommend mdfind but I am going to accept your answer anyway :)

Comment: That's kind. Glad I could steer you in the right direction. You can answer your own question though. I'd upvote that.