# What's a good program for syncing files between computers?

Tags: software-recommendation, data-synchronization

I've been using Synk from [Decimus](https://decimus.net/Synk) off and on for a few years to sync files between two Macs.

Since upgrading to Lion, Sync 6 has started hanging during the process of scanning before the sync. Upgrading to version 7 is $45 which seems like a lot.

Is there another program out there that does the same thing? I don't need it to sync the contents of files that have been changed on both computers, just copy the most recent version of a file (or a new file) from one to the other. I'd also like to be able to have it ignore files with a specific Finder label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to pay the $45 for the Synk update. I figured it would take more than an hour or two to try to get rsync to work with two-way syncing. It was worth $45 to me to not have to spend that time and to use a solution I already know will work.

Answer (score 5):

If you can use command-line tools, try `rsync`.

For the label part, see [Rsync filter: "OS X label"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53209/rsync-filter-os-x-label).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it looks like rsync is one-way only. I may create a file on either computer. Sorry if the original question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @SSteve, well, you could run `rsync` twice, but on the same host, targeting each host in turn.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how comfortable you are using Unix tools, but [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) should meet your needs (and it's open source). I don't know how well it supports Finder labels though.

Comment: I looked through the Ignore options and it doesn't look like it has the ability to ignore files based on metadata.

Answer (score 0):

For a two way sync there is a free application with a GUI named [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/). Although Carbon Copy Cloner is a visual interface around rsync, you don't need to have rsync installed as it is already included in the software package.

To sync with a remote Mac, there is the option to choose "Another Macintosh" as destination/target. Such a remote sync requires the installation of a 143 KB package on both the local and the remote Mac.

The sync is on demand/upon request or can be scheduled. Though my guess is you need to create 2 jobs: one for each sync direction.

Answer (score 0):

Another sync solution is the [$11.99 Apple App Store only](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/folderwatch/id408224368?mt=12) application named [FolderWatch](http://www.brothersroloff.com/folderwatch/).

Remote sync is unfortunately only done over AFP protocol. In other words you need to enable file sharing on the remote Mac.

The benefit is that the FolderWatch synchronization is done almost real-time. The application needs to be installed on both computers to synchronize in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Chronosync](http://www.econtechnologies.com/pages/cs/chrono_overview.html) for this.  You can schedule to sync weekly, daily, or hourly with any frequency you want.  You can sync one way or two way.  It can automatically send you email alerts when things don't work.  It runs quietly as a service in the background.  It's total automation, which works for me.  Totally worth it's $40 cost.